# Как анимировать последовательно UIBezier линии

Tags: ios, swift, анимация, animate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в Swift анимировать такую линию?

Я пробовал создавать маленькие `UIView` и анимировать их передвижение в `UIView.animate`. Также, отдельно я рисовал линии `UIBezier` и прикреплял их так, чтобы они проходили через центры маленьких View. В методе `CABasicAnimation` создавал анимированные переходы `"path"`.

Оказалось, эта анимация подходит, если они линейны (`.curveLinear`). Если мои анимированные View более динамичны, например, `.curveEaseIn`, то анимация линий смотрится нелепо, так как не совпадает с анимацией маленьких View.

Есть ли способ создать эти маленькие View, прикрепиться линиями к их центрам, и их не анимировать, чтобы линии сами следовали за ними?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: в swift не знаю но в svg вот так: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YzGaWEK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте для таких нужд `CAShapeLayer` и анимируйте его `path` при помощи `CABasicAnimation`. Либо, если нужно вот такое дрожание - при помощи `CASpringAnimation`.

Простой пример в действии: есть некий layer с путем (0,0)-(1,0) и будет он анимирован до (0,0)-(1,1)

```
// Начальный путь, условно (0,0)-(1,0)
let initialPath = UIBezierPath()
initialPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
initialPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
diagramLayer.path = initialPath.cgPath

...

// Анимируем до конечного, (0,0)-(1,1)
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation.fromValue = diagramLayer.path
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
animation.toValue = path.cgPath
animation.duration = 0.5
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [self] in
    diagramLayer.path = path.cgPath
}
diagramLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
CATransaction.commit()
```

[image: CABasicAnimation example 1]

Для дрожания в конце анимации нужно заменить `CABasicAnimation` на `CASpringAnimation` и переменными ниже можно регулировать поведение "пружины":

```
let animation = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation.damping = 5
animation.mass = 0.5
animation.initialVelocity = 0.1
animation.stiffness = 1500
// Остальное как в прошлом примере
```

[image: CASpringAnimation example 1]

Анимация сгенерированного пути посложнее:

[image: CASpringAnimation example 2]

Теперь добавление промежуточных, "переходных" путей для сгенерированного:

[image: CASpringAnimation example 3]

И наложение по таймингам:

[image: CASpringAnimation example 4]

P.S. Все эти коэффициенты, тайминг и прочее - это уже подбираете как хотите. Основное - есть вот такие инструменты для анимации и их можно применить как угодно.